# Ordering of tasks in TPL

Tags: c#, asynchronous, concurrency, task-parallel-library, concurrent-programming

If I have the following code

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static Task<int> GetSuperLargeNumber()
        {
            var main = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                                                 {
                                                     Thread.Sleep(1000);
                                                     return 100;
                                                 });
            var second = main.ContinueWith(x => Console.WriteLine("Second: " + x.Result), TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent);
            var third = main.ContinueWith(x => Console.WriteLine("Third: " + x.Result), TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent);

            return main.ContinueWith(x  =>
                                             {
                                                 Task.WaitAll(second, third);
                                                 return x.Result;
                                             });
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GetSuperLargeNumber().ContinueWith(x => Console.WriteLine("Complete"));

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I want main to start first, then 2 dependencies can start after that which in parallel which are first and second. I want to then return a future with the value for the caller to add a continuation on. However i want to ensure second and third have run first. Is the code below the best way to achieve this? Seems kinda clunky

Comment: The way you use `AttachedToParent` doesn't make any sense. The “parent” is the currently executing `Task`, but there isn't any in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with TPL, but isn't this what [`ContinueWhenAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321473.aspx) is for?

```
static Task<int> GetSuperLargeNumber()
{
    var main = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                                         {
                                             Thread.Sleep(1000);
                                             return 100;
                                         });
    var second = main.ContinueWith(
        x => Console.WriteLine("Second: " + x.Result),
        TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent);
    var third = main.ContinueWith(
        x => Console.WriteLine("Third: " + x.Result),
        TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent);

    return Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(
        new[] { second, third },
        (twotasks) => /* not sure how to get the original result here */);
    }
```

I don't know how to get `main`'s result from the completed `second` and `third` (contained in `twotasks`), but maybe you can modify them to pass through the result.

Edit: Or, as [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/532057/alex) points out, use

```
Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(new[] { main, second, third }, (threetasks) => ...
```

and read the result from `threetasks[0]`.

Comment: You can `ContinueWhenAll(new [] { main, second, third})` and it will allow you to extract the result of `main`.

Comment: @Alex Huh, that would work, thanks :) It's still a bit weird because you _know_ that `main` must be done if `second` and `third` are done, but it's a cleaner workaround than the original.

Answer (score 0):

This would suffice:

```
static Task<int> GetSuperLargeNumber()
{
    var main = Task.Factory.StartNew<int>(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        return 100;
    });
    var second = main.ContinueWith(x => Console.WriteLine("Second: " + x.Result), TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent);
    var third = main.ContinueWith(x => Console.WriteLine("Third: " + x.Result), TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent);

    Task.WaitAll(second, third);

    return main;
}
```